# Android : OpenGL 2.0 first person camera

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So I am trying to learn OpenGL 2.0 on Android, I did play quite a bit with OpenGL 1 on iOS and really enjoyed it.

My simple question is about the camera and making a 3D environment where you can move around (First person)

Should I be using

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
```

to control the camera and where I am in the world (updated on onDrawFrame) , or setting that on the onSurfaceCreated (once) and using

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mViewMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(mViewMatrix, 0, mMoveY, 0.0f, mMoveX);
Matrix.rotateM(mViewMatrix, 0, mDeltaY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(mViewMatrix, 0, mDeltaX, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

instead which feels like I am rotating the world around me.

I have seen examples where they do either, on OpenGL 1 I used to use GLLookAt

Comment: Use the one that produces correct results, obviously. Both can be used, since `setLookAt` is just a higher abstraction over translations and rotations.

Comment: Use the one that best fits you and your use case. In OpenGL all you do is rotating the world around you, there is no actual camera (and even more so in ES 2, where you have complete control of the transformation in the shaders anyway). In the end `setLookAt` doesn't do much else than compute a rotation and translation of the *"world"*, in the same way like a bunch of `translate` and `rotate` calls do, it's just a nicer (or higher level) interface for certain use cases. If you already have your `mMove` and `mDelta` values, the 2nd method seems easier.

Comment: Pleas explain to me how is lookAt the same as calling a bunch of translate and rotate method calls? The translate part really isn't that much of a work, but rotate has to do sin/cos operations to create the rotation matrix and then multiply the 2 matrices. LookAt on the other hand directly inserts the 3 base vectors and translation into the matrix. The base vectors being: X-axis cross(forward, up), Y-axis up, Z-axis forward = look-eye. Each of them is represented by a column respectively. Although I do agree if the result is the same, use what suits you best.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time and reply, if anyone wants to post that as a answer then I will mark it off, I had a feeling that LookAt did do this under the hood, using the translate and rotate just seems easier for me to understand.  However I was getting issues with my perspective so when I turn a cube straight in front of me, got quite wide as it went around me.  I will post this as another question

Comment: @MaticOblak Well, yeah, rotate will use some trigonometry. I didn't say they perform the exact same arithmetic (look at the comment), I just said conceptually they both just create a rigid body transformation matrix (rotate+translate). It isn't that setLookAt does something extremely magical (which I'm not sure the OP is aware of). Of course the actual implementation is completely undefined (well ok, not so undefined), but the outcome is the same (and really, this bunch of trigonometrics doesn't matter for a per-frame constructed matrix, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the two methods is fine since you can get same results. The general difference is about how you want to store your objects state. For a 3D environment I would always use 3 vectors to determine the object state (position, forward, up) and use modified version of lookAt and modelMatrix that can place the object with same parameters as lookAt. The upside of this approach is that you can directly place the parameters depending on other object, for instance: A guided missile is following you and is always turned towards you no mater where you are or how you move. Then its forward vector is simply `taregetPosition-missilePosition` (usually normalized). On the other hand if you have to compute the angles you have quite some work, directly `asin`, `acos` and a few `if` statements for each of the 2 angles. Next for instance simple moving around the room, going forward: If you use base vectors, then `position = position+forward*speedFactor` while with angles you again have to compute what way are you facing and then do the same... (there are quite a few situations where that is useful)

But there are downsides. You need to have your own system to move and rotate those vectors. For instance if you want to say turn to your left for 45 degrees it would look something like this:

```
forward = (forward+cross(up,forward)*tan(45)).normalized
```

and this only works for angle in interval (-90, 90). It gets quite the same when turning up but you need to also correct the up vector.

So to wrap it up, IF you create all the methods to work with base vectors (rotations, look at, model matrix...) they are a real labor saving method. But it simply depends on the project you are writing to decide what to use.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying, going with the second method, I  have my rotation in degree's out of the box however, I need to work out my position(X,Y,Z) in space.  Do you have any idea on how I would do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: So if you use rotateM then you know the players rotation as you set it, however you dont know there position in space because you use translateM and rotateM together.  For example rotate 45 degrees and then move forward 1 step, how would you then know your x,y,z pos

Comment: Oh, that is not really the problem as it sounds. You should always keep the x,y,z position and the 2 rotations. Then you would first call the translate and then the 2 rotation calls. The only thing you need to ask is (when moving in first person) where forward is so you are able to make such a control (its on (cos(phiX), sin(phiX), sin(phiY)) so its not much of a big deal). But never use the rotation first, if you did what I think you were thinking you would have to trace all the input calls (go forward for A, turn left for B, go forward for C, turn up for D...) and recreate the current state.

Comment: You are being a real help honest, I keep switching between the 2 methods, I raised this issue for the other one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022821/android-opengl-2-0-rotation-moving-the-camera-using-matrix-setlookatm